# AIR for iOS app crashes on launch - only on i Pad1

Tags: ios, ipad, air

Been working on an iPad book app in FlashBuilder 4.6. Early on there were some performance issues with iPad1/3 until learning about GPU rendermode and setting the StageQuality to low. These helped immensely.

However, recently the app starting crashing on startup - only on iPad1. For example page 1 of the app which had worked weeks ago would now crash. After more research, it seemed that the static references to all the page classes that were put in the ViewController were the issue. They seemed to be overwhelming the memory. When I put only a static reference to page1 in the VC it worked. And then in page 1 were static references to page 2 or 3. Or whatever pages it might link to. Now, after reworking the 70 other pages to only static reference the pages they need, it is crashing again.

My question is this, if I have page 1 with a static reference to page 2 and 3. And each of those have references...all down the line to say page 70, are all those in essence getting loaded into memory at startup?

The bigger question is how best to manage the memory of an AIR app that will have ~ 120+ "pages" or views in MVC parlance? Ideally, I only want the dynamically created view in memory but don't think it's working.

I've read the other posts here and was thinking about loading/unloading swfs that have references to needed classes via ApplicationDomain.

One interesting thing noticed is this. When launching the app in the debugger, it traces out terminated and the app quits. However, when double clicking the iPad home button, it shows the app still running. Not sure why that is?

Pardon the lengthy description.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
MTG

Comment: Are you building some sort of magazine or catalog ?

Comment: Thanks for responding, pardon my delay. I'm building an interactive book.